# Mongodb query based on condition of deep array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have objects in my DB like this

> {   seasons:[
> {
> episodes:[{ status: "OK" },{ status: "Not OK" }]
> },
> {
> episodes:[{ status: "Not OK" },{ status: "Not OK" }]
> }    ] }

Each document has a key named `seasons`, which is an array of objects. Each season, has another property named `episodes`, which is an array of objects as well. I need to do a query that returns any document that has any value in `episodes` with status "OK".

for instance, above document must be returned cause it has one episode with "OK" status.

What is the most efficient way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
db.collection.find({
  "seasons.episodes.status": "OK"
})
```

Mongo Playground example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/snJfuoAagRR).

With an index on `{ 'seasons.episodes.status': 1 }`  this should be quite efficient.

Comment: Yes it is. Simpler than I thought :)) Thank you.